# PreferenceActivity, Headers, and onDestroy being called when the activity is visible

Tags: android

I'm running into a bit of a problem.

I have a PreferenceActivity with a list of headers, each pointing to a fragment. Those fragments are shown as a single pane (small display).

In order to exit a header fragment and go back to the list of headers of the PreferenceActivity itself, I press the back button (as a user), or call `getActivity().onBackPressed()` if I need to get back to the list after the user pressed a button on the UI.

This brings me back to the header list PreferenceActivity, but it also calls the `onDestroy()` method of that activity.

#### This is what I don't understand:

Why does it call the `onDestroy()` when the activity itself is clearly visible? And why doesn't it call the `onCreate()` after that, again, since the activity is visible?

This also has a side effect of calling the `onReset()` of a loader I use to create the list of data that produces the headers in the first place. That in turn makes it look like the header list hasn't changed, even when I have removed an item from the list, and thus reduced the number of headers. If I actually close and reopen the PreferenceActivity, the header list will be correct, which shows that the loader itself is working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what is happening here without code. But from the sounds of it you are calling `onBackPressed()` for the activity, thus what happens happens irrespective of fragments. Try overriding `onBackPressed()` in the activity and handle your fragment transactions there.

Answer (score 0):

Headers launch new activities in single pane mode. That is likely why you are seeing onDestroy() for the same named activity, as it launches the same activity with a different intent it seems.

For future readers.